# WPF two-way binding with WinForms control in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have a simple demo `WPF` application. Main page contains `DataGrid` binded to the `ObservableCollection` of `RowVM` class with `DateTime` property `MyDate`. I created `CalendarEx` - `UserControl` that wraps windows forms control `DateTimePicker` and expose `SelectedDate` dependency property.

I expect that when I select a date in `CalendarEx` in `DataGrid` row it also changes `MyDate` column. But it does not work - the value of `MyDate` column never changed and `MyDate` property setter is never called.

Somehow it works outside `DataGrid` - with `SimpleDate` property and `StandAlone` `CalendarEx`. When I change the value of `StandAlone` - value of the `Label` changed immediately.

**Do somebody know what happens and how to fix it?**

MainWindow.xaml:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding Path=SimpleDate}"></Label>
        <local:CalendarEx x:Name="StandAlone" SelectedDate="{Binding Path=SimpleDate, Mode=TwoWay}"></local:CalendarEx>

        <DataGrid x:Name="MyGrid" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Rows, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <local:CalendarEx SelectedDate="{Binding Path=MyDate, Mode=TwoWay}"></local:CalendarEx>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="MyDate" Binding="{Binding Path=MyDate}" Width="90" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
```

CalendarEx.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestCalendar.CalendarEx"
             ...
             xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms">
    <Grid>
        <WindowsFormsHost>
            <wf:DateTimePicker x:Name="MyPicker" />
        </WindowsFormsHost>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

CalendarEx.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class CalendarEx : UserControl
{
    public DateTime SelectedDate
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(SelectedDatePoperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedDatePoperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedDatePoperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedDate", typeof(DateTime), typeof(CalendarEx));

    public CalendarEx()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyPicker.ValueChanged += MyPicker_ValueChanged;
    }

    private void MyPicker_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SelectedDate = MyPicker.Value;
    }
}
```